# Using arguments in a .vimrc command

Tags: vimrc, user-commands

I've discovered that I can edit the .vimrc file to create custom commands and would like to create simpler [search and replace](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace) alternative commands, but have no idea how to edit `%s/foo/bar/gc` so that it uses the words I pass after the `:command` in vim instead of 'foo' and 'bar.'
Would prefer a simple solution not requiring me to learn vimscript.

Comment: Why not use `:%s/foo/bar/gc`?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the `:%s` command, you are already using some very simple VimScript. So much for not learning it :)

If you want to create your custom command, you can use e.g.

```
com! -nargs=1 Replace :%s/<args>/gc
```

This defines a new command `:Replace` and you can use `:Replace foo/bar`  to have all foo be replaced by bar across the complete document.

This is basically as simple and straight forward as possible, however this requires you to always supply an argument in the form `searchterm/replaceterm` e.g. you need to include the slash, so that dynamically a new command can be build up.

You could get very much sophisticated however, e.g. add some error management, use 2 arguments for searching and replacing, use a specific `magic` setting, so that it will handle e.g. `.` and `\` correctly or how to handle the `/` if it appears in the search or replace term.

This however requires using a function and doing a bit more of processing of the arguments and is way much out of scope, if you do not want to learn VimScript.